# Компиляция Java проекта с JDBC

Tags: java

[image: Проект]

Есть проект на Java, в нем используется JDBC. Как правильно компилировать такой проект, используя `javac`?

Если я нахожусь в директории `db_prog`, то команда `javac -cp . -d bin/ src/edu/mycompany/data/main/SimpleJDBCRunner.java` не работает.
И такая не работает `javac -cp ".:mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" -d bin/ src/edu/mycompany/data/main/SimpleJDBCRunner.java`

Но такая команда будет работать `javac -cp "src/:mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" -d bin/ src/edu/mycompany/data/main/SimpleJDBCRunner.java`

Comment: Правильно использовать maven или ant.

Comment: @Vartlok, да, но это единичный случай сборки вручную, для понимания как происходит сборка.

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы ожидаете в качестве ответа. У вас же получилось скомпилировать последней командой

Comment: @Vartlok, почему не работает `-cp .`, почему именно в таком виде нужно указывать, ведь если у меня будет намного больше библиотек, то придется указывать их все вручную (сборщики не рассматриваем)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `classpath` не обязательно, точно указывать название `jar` файлов, можно определить их через маску.

```
javac edu/mycompany/data/main/SimpleJDBCRunner.java -d ../bin -cp "../*:."
```

команду нужно запускать из директории src

Comment: Ваша команда не видит пакет  edu.mycompany.data.subject.

Comment: в каком пакете находится класс?

Comment: `Abonent` и `Entity` в `package edu.mycompany.data.subject`;
`SimpleJDBCRunner` в `package edu.mycompany.data.main`;

Comment: поправил с поправкой на другие классы

Comment: А почему не работает компиляция из директории `db_prog` у параметром `-cp .`? Как это устроено?

Comment: Хорошо. Начнем с того, что такое classpath. Это переменная окружения путь до директории или файла в котором javac ищет классы. Если мы хотим подключить jar файлы то нам нужно явно задавать путь до архива(см. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) поэтому вариант с точкой не работал

Comment: Почему нужно запускать javac из директории где находятся пакеты проекта или явно указывать эту директорию? Потому что javac сопоставляет название пакета и название директорий пытаясь по этим путям найти исходный .java файл